# Combine keyup, keypress and onblur events in jquery

Tags: jquery, validation, keypress

i have a div that is load dynamically into my page with an ajax request. 
In this div i have severall input all with the same class but different ID's

Those inputs have a keyup function, a keypress function and a onblur function.

The problem is i want that the user only can type in numbers and use the TABULATOR.

I use this function here

```
function validatenum(event) {
    var key = window.event ? event.keyCode : event.which;

    if (event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 46 
        || event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 39
    ) {
        return true;
    } else if (key < 48 || key > 57) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

and I call it with:

```
<input type="text" id="31_w_pr" class="order_sizes" 
    onkeypress="validatenum(event);" />
```

But it doesn't work. I can type in whatever I want.

Does anyone have an idea as to how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you not need to call `event.preventDefault();` when you want the keypress not to take effect?

Comment: Sry i don't understand what you mean. Please be patient i am from Germany and dont understand everything :-S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<input type="text" id="31_w_pr" class="order_sizes" 
    onkeypress="return validatenum(event);" />
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/afqf9/

However, consider [separating your JavaScript and HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_Javascript).

Comment: @Jings: Awesome! Glad I could help.  Please accept the answer if it worked for you!